# Emacs `start-process` seems to mangle process output

Tags: windows, shell, emacs, console, elisp

I am at the bottom of a problem - I don't see how to dig any deeper because I am now running `start-process` from the `process.C` file. Which is in Emacs internals and the next step seem to be looking at the C code.

Here's the my problem. When I run

```
(let ((default-directory "C:/Users/esharapov/.emacs.d/"))
  (apply 'start-process "ag" (get-buffer-create "test")
         "c:\\App\\emacs\\libexec\\emacs\\24.5\\i686-pc-mingw32\\cmdproxy.exe"
         (list "-c" "\"ag\" \"--nocolor\"  \"--literal\" \"--line-number\" \"--smart-case\" \"--nogroup\" \"--column\" \"--stats\" \"--\" \"keymap-on\" \".\"")))
```

I get in the buffer following output

```
194:15:    (defmacro keymap-on-key (name keys)
233:9:       (keymap-on-key ctl-x-f-map "C-x f")
572:7:     (keymap-on-key ctl-z-w-map "C-z w")
194:15:    (defmacro keymap-on-key (name keys)

233:9:       (keymap-on-key ctl-x-f-map "C-x f")

572:7:     (keymap-on-key ctl-z-w-map "C-z w")

6 matches
382 files searched
8993756 bytes searched
0.446822 seconds

Process ag finished
```

If I run it in the Windows command prompt as

```
c:\\App\\emacs\\libexec\\emacs\\24.5\\i686-pc-mingw32\\cmdproxy.exe /c "C:\\App\\bin\\ag.exe --nocolor  --literal --line-number --smart-case --nogroup --column --stats -- keymap-on ."
```

I get following output

```
#configuration.org#:194:15:    (defmacro keymap-on-key (name keys)
#configuration.org#:233:9:       (keymap-on-key ctl-x-f-map "C-x f")
#configuration.org#:572:7:     (keymap-on-key ctl-z-w-map "C-z w")
configuration.org:194:15:    (defmacro keymap-on-key (name keys)
configuration.org:233:9:       (keymap-on-key ctl-x-f-map "C-x f")
configuration.org:572:7:     (keymap-on-key ctl-z-w-map "C-z w")
6 matches
382 files searched
8993756 bytes searched
0.483917 seconds
```

Noticed the difference ? When I use `start-process` the file name is being removed from the process output. Does anyone know what's the issue here ?

*UPDATE*

I conducted few more experiments comparing output of various commands in the `CMD` shell and in Emacs `shell`. One obvious contender was `grep` command

```
(let ((default-directory "C:/Users/esharapov/Dev/Test/"))
  (apply 'start-process "grep" (get-buffer-create "test") "c:\\App\\emacs\\libexec\\emacs\\24.5\\i686-pc-mingw32\\cmdproxy.exe" (list "-c" "\"grep\" \"-nH\"  \"-e\" \"Metlife\" \"*.txt\"")))
```

Prints

```
Evgeniy_Review.txt:192:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
Evgeniys_20141031.txt:16:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT

Process grep finished
```

The output of the console is identical

```
C:\Users\esharapov\Dev\Test>grep -nH -e Metlife *.txt
Evgeniy_Review.txt:192:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
Evgeniys_20141031.txt:16:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
```

Now for `ag` command

```
(let ((default-directory "C:/Users/esharapov/Dev/Test/"))
  (apply 'start-process "ag" (get-buffer-create "test") "c:\\App\\emacs\\libexec\\emacs\\24.5\\i686-pc-mingw32\\cmdproxy.exe" (list "-c" "\"ag\" --nocolor --nogroup \"Metlife\" .")))
```

Prints out the following:

```
   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT

Process ag finished
```

While in the console (CMD shell)

```
C:\Users\esharapov\Dev\Test>ag --nocolor --nogroup Metlife .
Evgeniys_20141031.txt:16:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
Evgeniy_Review.txt:192:   1. Finishing Harmony Docker container and presenting it to the Metlife SWAT
```

Seems like replacing `cmdproxy` with say `bash` from Git for Windows or `cmd`  doesn't make a difference and results are the same.

So, it is something in `ag` console command that makes a difference. On the other hand what's going on that `start-process` output is different from cmd output ?

Versions:

- Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
- GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2015-04-11 on LEG570

Comment: I would look at `ag` rather than Emacs as the likely culprit.  If you run it without a controlling terminal, with a reduced environment, etc, can you reproduce the output you get under Emacs?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need to include the `--filename` parameter to ag to fix that.

As the reason of the divergence of outputs, my guess is that it would be related to environment variables.  Those might different between emacs and prompt (the path of ag binary, the HOME where ag looks for its defaults, etc).

Comment: No. Neither `--filename` nor `--heading` helps.

Comment: Besides, it seems to manifest more general flaw - mangling the process output.

Comment: At help-gnu-emacs@gnu.org there is a chance, some of the core-developers will see it.